# Can I cast native primitive type into a JNI primitive type without worrying about endianness?

Tags: c, java-native-interface

Let's say I have

```
const uint16_t n = 0x0001;
```

Then can I cast like this?

```
const jint j = (jint) n;
```

Without worrying about endianness of the native platform?

**Supplement**

I have a function changes a value into an char array.

```
char * value_to_array(void * value, const size_t size) {
  char * array = malloc(size);
  if (array != NULL) {
    memcpy(array, value, size);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Now I should care about the endianness, right? What about the above simple cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then can I cast like this?

Yes. [JNI primitive types are machine-dependent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp428).

Your second example preserves whatever endian-ness was present in the source, which you haven't specified.

Comment: So, in the first cast, I can safely return the casted `jint` to the Java side and the value will be `0x0001`, not `0x0100`? Right?

Comment: @JinKwon I've answered that.